# Django custom auth backend not recognized on Apache

Tags: python, django, mod-python

I'm trying to deploy my Django application to an Apache2 based server with mod_python. I've set the handlers right and made the configuration to make mod_python work with my project. My project implements a custom auth backend to connect my users to twitter, and my backend implementation is on:

```
myproject
|- backends/
```

directory.Everything seems to be working fine, my pages load and I can make read/write operations properly. But whenever I try to login with my Twitter account, application fires an exception telling me:

Error importing authentication backend backends.twitteroauth: "No module named backends.twitteroauth"

In my settings.py, I'm registering my backend as

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
   'myproject.backends.twitteroauth.TwitterBackend',
)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: This is an issue with gunicorn too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing database solved my problem. As far as I can guess, if a user is logged, his corresponding login backend is kept as a session variable on the database. My settings.py file was

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
   'backends.twitteroauth.TwitterBackend',
)
```

before I made the correction. Changing settings.py and restarting the application was simply not enough. You have to remove session related records from db too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that python cannot find the module `twitteroauth`. What is the name of the file `TwitterBackend` is in? Also make sure that there is a `__init__.py` file in `backends` to mark it as a package.

**edit:**

What happens if you run the shell

```
python manage.py shell
```

and try to import it there?

```
from myproject.backends.twitteroauth import TwitterBackend
```

As anything else works fine, I guess `myproject` is in your python path.

Comment: TwitterBackend is a class and the file is twitteroauth. I have __init__.py inside the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that backends is on the python path and has a **init**.py file in the folder.